# DotNet 5.0 Razor Page - get Current User from HTTPContext

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am very new to this topic.

I've created an Azure App Service with authentication (microsoft.com) and deployed a dotnet 5.0 web app with razor pages.

Basically, I just want to get the user's name on the page from the PageModel. Can anybody tell me how to do that?

I've already examined and tested many code snippets but none of them work.

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want to access the user identity in the asp.net core razor page.

I suggest you could refer to below codes:

```
        var user =  User.Identity.Name;
```

Besides, this code will just read the user which is already login in. If you don't provide any authentication sechma in your application, it will not show any login username in it.